# First MySQL insert is extremely slow

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am building a Rails application with MySQL db. My database has several simple tables. However, I sometimes experienced very slow Insert SQL execution (for the first INSERT) even though the data is very simple.

My table looks like this:

```
mysql> describe video_tags;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ip         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| video_id   | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| content    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And the INSERT SQL execution:

```
mysql> insert into video_tags (ip, video_id, user_id, content) values('115.77.185.243', 426127, 63, 'test');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 2 warnings (9.37 sec)
```

Why it tooks up to more than 9 seconds just to insert this simple data? If I run the same insert again, it is very fast

```
mysql> insert into video_tags (ip, video_id, user_id, content) values('115.77.185.243', 426127, 63, 'another test');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

I have no idea why this issue occurs. Do you have any idea what causes can be?

Comment: Perhaps there is some first time configuration for one or more indices which happens at the first insert into an empty table.

Comment: Not really because even though my table has some data already, this still happens.

Comment: Do you have an ORM framework running with Ruby?

Comment: Yes, ActiveRecord. But here I am executing the query directly from MySQL terminal

Comment: The Lazy Log I'm experiencing the same thing with lots of (first time) inserts as well. Takes over 1 minute. After that it only takes seconds. Have you found any solutions / hints / tips ? Thanks.